# AJAX posting issue in React JS

Tags: ajax, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch, axios

I have been doing React JS a while, but only front-end. Now I would like to spice it up with external data. So I tried with AXIOS / FETCH unfortunatelly both of them produced this miserable result. Here is the challenge:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/backend/datatest/src.json", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: 'Hubot',
      login: 'hubot',
    })
  })


  fetch('http://localhost:8080/backend/datatest/src.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(json) {
    console.log(json)
  })
```

Its basicly a copy-paste from GITHUB of fetch, assuring nothing would go badly. "GET" function works perfectly, but i got problems with POST-ing. I keep getting back the same error mesage

POST http://localhost:8080/backend/datatest/src.json 404 (Not Found)

HOWEVER! GET works perfectly.

I am using React JS, Redux, node JS. This JSON file didnt get installed at any server. In your opinion what would be the next step.

Regards,
Koppany

Comment: can you show your server side routes that are you are attempting to call?

Comment: I guess here lies the first problem. I didnt set up any server just trying to reach an external JSON file to load and modify data. Honestly seeing GET worked, didnt think there is more to do.

Comment: @Koppany, I would recommend storing your api url in a `const` as well as your api key, then use `axios.post()`, instead of `fetch()`.